# Add new record to oracle database from Java Gui

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a new record to my oracle 11g database from javaNetbeans but it's not working. Here is my code.

```
private void InsertbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     // TODO add your handling code here:
     String PositionType=jTextField1.getText().trim();
     String PositionTypeDesc=jTextField2.getText().trim();
     try{ 
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver");
         Connection c= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:HRM","System","jayden");
         java.sql.Statement st=c.createStatement();
         st.executeUpdate("Insert into PositionType values('"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jTextField2.getText()+"')");
         System.out.println();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Null,"DATA SACVE!");
     }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
     }    
}
```

Comment: any exception you got ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the issue?

Comment: I have tried debugging it but am not finding the records in the database

Comment: You may want to actually do something in that `catch` instead of just ignoring what the exception says. Even just a `e.printStackTrace()` for starters.

Comment: You may wish to look into using a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct to handle your connection state for you.

Comment: When you get your code running, maybe you want to post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some hints to improve your style.

Comment: Please don't put *it's urgent* in your question, [Stack Overflow is not the place to get an answer to a question quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/833070), only a correct answer which can take time

Comment: And please use a `PreparedStatement` instead of this. Inserting textfield value like this is really not a good idea... Search about SQL Injection

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here:

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
}
```

Now you have a problem and

- Don't know what went wrong
- Don't know where it happend
- Don't even known if something went wrong

When getting an exception, you should at least log it somehow, and deal with the situation properly (either rethrow it, or do error handling by showing an error dialog or something). The least you should do is:

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which prints the exception (type and message) as well as the stacktrace (invocation chain, with details on which methods / code lines the exception occurred.

That will give you insights on what went wrong and what to fix.

Comment: Please can i get a sample add new record command from java GUI into Oracle database

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the class name is wrong.

"oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver" is not plausible, try "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" where the class name begins with an upper-case O. By convention, Java class names should always begin with an upper-case letter.

But make sure to install a proper error handling as well, as suggested by the other answers / comments.